# How to specify a file path in web.xml file

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

i am developing an application in java and i am new to this java ee platform.I have a dataset file called "51Degrees-EnterpriseV3_2.dat" in my resource folder. how do i specify the path of this in my web.xml file and how do i retrieve the file in code?

Comment: Are you using Maven? When you say your resource folder, do you mean `src/main/resources`? Do you simply want to access the file in your code or do you have some other reason to have it specified in your `web.xml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In web.xml , you can add

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>you can mention here localtion variable name</param-name>
  <param-value>location here </param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: and how do i get the file in service class?

Answer (score 1):

The other answer shows the correct way to add the parameter to your `web.xml`. Which for the 51Degrees V3.2 data file would look like this:

```
<context-param>
    <description>The name of the device database.</description>
    <param-name>BINARY_FILE_PATH</param-name>
    <param-value>51Degrees-EnterpriseV3_2.dat</param-value>
</context-param>
```

As far as I know, there is not a way to get a resource which is located in the resources path (it's an XML file so the `.getResource(name)` method cannot be used). However, as you have a `web.xml` file, I assume this is a web project (i.e. `.war` rather than `.jar`)? If this is the case, then the `WEB-INF` directory is what you need. Files in here are also packaged up like resources, but can be more easily consumed by a `.war` package.

If you put your data file in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/`, which is used as the root by the web project. So the above XML example will work if the path to your data file is:

```
src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/51Degrees-EnterpriseV3_2.dat
```

As a sidenote, there is more documentation on configuring 51Degrees in a Java web app [here](https://51degrees.com/Developers/Documentation/APIs/Java-V32/Web-Apps/Configuration/Webxml)